# El Capitan broke my NSView animations

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, nsview, osx-elcapitan, nsanimationcontext

I have a Mac app that uses a `NSAnimationContext` animation grouping to animate one `NSView` offscreen and another `NSView` onscreen.  Prior to beginning the animation grouping I position the offscreen `NSView` in the position that I want it to originate from when it animates onscreen.

Under Yosemite and earlier versions this worked perfectly but under El Capitan it is as if the `NSView` never gets positioned in the start position that I specify so it animates onscreen from the wrong direction.

```
//Position offscreen view at correct starting point.
offscreenView.frame = STARTING_OFFSCREEN_RECT;

//Create animation grouping
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:animationDuration];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setCompletionHandler:^{
    /*
    Do cleanup stuff here
    */
}];

//Move the views
onscreenView.frame = ENDING_OFFSCREEN_RECT:
offscreenView.frame = ENDING_ONSCREEN_RECT;

//End Grouping
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

I've debugged this to the best of my ability and it appears to me that the setting of `offscreenView`'s frame at the very beginning is not actually occurring.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same but when animating NSLayoutConstraint's constant. My temporary workaround is animating the alpha instead of the frame so the view doesn't appear out of nowhere, but I'm not happy with that.

Answer (score 1):

I had very similar problem - `offscreenView` **sometimes** starts from the wrong position.
The `offscreenView.layer` appears to be messed up.

I fixed it by adding the following to my clean-up code:

```
onscreenView.layer = nil;
```

so that the next time the `offscreenView` is animated it will start with clean layer.
Or maybe in your case reset the layer before starting the animation:

```
offscreenView.layer = nil;

//Position offscreen view at correct starting point.
offscreenView.frame = STARTING_OFFSCREEN_RECT;

//Create animation grouping
...
```

NOTE:

In my animation I add the `offscreenView` every time to the superView:

```
//Position offscreen view at correct starting point.
offscreenView.frame = STARTING_OFFSCREEN_RECT;

[superView addSubview:offscreenView];

//Create animation grouping
...
```

And in the clean-up code I remove the `onscreenView` as well:

```
[onscreenView removeFromSuperview];
onscreenView.layer = nil;
```